# clearInterval не понятно работает

Tags: javascript

Почему не получается отключить таймер?

Он просто продолжает дальше работать. Юзаю такую функцию, потому что надо запускать таймер в одной функции, а останавливать в другой. Как правильно?

```
function refresh(e) {
    time = $.cookie("time");

    if(e != 'stop') {
        var c = setInterval(update, time+"000");
    } else {
        clearInterval(c);
    }
}

function chating() {
    if(time == null) {
        $.cookie("time", "5", {expires: 30, path: "/"});    
        time = $.cookie("time");
    }

    refresh();
}

function setting() { 
    refresh('stop');
}
```

Comment: Может Вы хотели вместо **setInterval** использовать **setTimeout**?

Comment: Ну смотря как. У меня чат должен обновляться каждые 5 секунд. А не один раз через 5 сек.

Answer (score 8):

Все из-за того, что возвращенный id таймера записывается в локальную переменную, соответственно теряется при выходе из функции.

Стоит сохранять в глобальную

```
var c;
function refresh(e) {
    time = $.cookie("time");

    if(e != 'stop') {
        c = setInterval(update, time+"000");
    } else {
        clearInterval(c);
    }
}
```